# Error uploading image to server in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to upload image to the server. But i am getting error like-

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281a1d050'
*** First throw call stack:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
*+(void)uploadImage: (NSArray *_Nullable)imagesArr productId: (NSString *_Nullable)productId featured:(BOOL)featured downloadProgress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress * _Nullable downloadProgress))downloadProgressBlock completionHandler:(nullable void(^)(NSError * _Nullable error,id _Nullable response))completionHandler{
    REQUEST_TYPE type = REQUEST_TYPE_JSON;
    REQUEST_METHOD method = REQUEST_METHOD_POST;

    NSMutableDictionary *headerDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [headerDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",GET_TOKEN] forKey:@"Authorization"];
    [headerDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/json"] forKey:@"Content-Type"];
    ServerConnection *connection = [ServerConnection getInstance];


    NSString *createProducAPIURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",URL_BASE,URL_PRODUCTIMAGE_UPLOAD];

    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
//
    NSMutableArray *imageDictArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



    int position = 0;

    for (NSString *url in imagesArr) {

        NSMutableDictionary *imageDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [imageDict setObject:url forKey:@"src"];
        [imageDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:position] forKey:@"position"];

        [imageDictArr addObject:imageDict];

        position++;
    }
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagesArr[0], 0.5);
    NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];
    NSLog(@"image: %@", imageData);
    [parameters setObject:productId forKey:@"product_id"];
    [parameters setObject:encodedString forKey:@"file"];
    [connection dataTask:createProducAPIURL parameters:parameters requestType:type method:method headerDict:(NSDictionary *_Nullable)headerDict uploadProgress:^(NSProgress * _Nullable serveruploadProgress) {

    } downloadProgress:^(NSProgress * _Nullable downloadProgress) {

        downloadProgressBlock(downloadProgress);

    } completionHandler:^(id  _Nullable jsonSerializedData, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        completionHandler(error,jsonSerializedData);

    }];

}
 -(void) dataTask:(NSString *_Nullable)URLString parameters:(NSDictionary *_Nullable)parameters requestType:(REQUEST_TYPE)type method:(REQUEST_METHOD)method headerDict:(NSDictionary *_Nullable)headerDict uploadProgress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress * _Nullable uploadProgress))uploadProgressBlock downloadProgress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress * _Nullable downloadProgress))downloadProgressBlock completionHandler:(nullable void (^)(id _Nullable jsonSerializedData,  NSError * _Nullable error))completionHandler
{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request;

//    URLString = [URLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];
    URLString = [URLString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];

    switch (type) {
        case REQUEST_TYPE_NORMAL:
            request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:[self requestMethod:method] URLString:URLString parameters:parameters error:nil];
            break;

        case REQUEST_TYPE_JSON:
        {
            request = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:[self requestMethod:method] URLString:URLString parameters:nil error:nil];

            NSError *error;
            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
            if(!error)
            {
                [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

                NSLog(@"Request body %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
            }
            else{

                completionHandler(nil,error);
                return;
            }
        }
            break;

        default:
            request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:[self requestMethod:method] URLString:URLString parameters:parameters error:nil];
            break;
    }

    if(!isNullObject(headerDict))
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headerDict];

    NSLog(@"TOKEN:%@",[USER_DEFAULTS objectForKey:kKeyToken]);
    NSLog(@"REQUEST URL:%@",URLString);
    NSLog(@"Request body %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [_manager dataTaskWithRequest:request uploadProgress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

        NSLog(@"Upload Progress: %f",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
        uploadProgressBlock(uploadProgress);

    } downloadProgress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {

        NSLog(@"downloadProgress : %f",downloadProgress.fractionCompleted);
        downloadProgressBlock(downloadProgress);

    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if(!error)
        {
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            //            NSInteger statusCode = [HTTPResponse statusCode];

            NSLog(@"URL:%@",HTTPResponse.URL);
            NSLog(@"response:%@",string);

            if([string rangeOfString:@"<!DOCTYPE html>"].location != NSNotFound){
                string = [self  stringByStrippingHTML:string];
                NSData *resObj = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                id responseObject1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:resObj options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                completionHandler(responseObject1,error);
            }
            else{
                id responseObject1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                completionHandler(responseObject1,error);
            }
        }
        else{

            NSLog(@"error:%@",error);

            id responseObject2 = nil;

            if(responseObject!=nil)
            {
                NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"response:%@",string);
                responseObject2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
            }


            completionHandler(responseObject2,error);
        }
    }];

    [dataTask resume];


}*
```

Comment: Which line? Which line exactly is causing the crash? It's a well known error, but you posted to many lines, it's hard to find where exactly (hidden calls).

Comment: Found: `for (NSString *url in imagesArr) {}`. So each object in `imagesArr` is a `NSString` object, right? `NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagesArr[0], 0.5);` Here, you are saying that the first item is a `UIImage` object. Clearly it can't be at the same time a `UIImage` and a `NSString`. And that's the line causing the error.